# "didRemoveListeners" (a nil value) when storyboard:purge/removeScene is called. How to add/remove DisplayObject via scene.view?

Tags: android, iphone, lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I need help with my little project here...

I have a game with two scenes (menu and game) and I can't change scenes correctly. My main problem is that I cannot remove all my scene.view DisplayObjects correctly since storyboard.purgeScene("game") generates this error:

```
"didRemoveListeners" (a nil value)
```

Here's my code explained:

- In "Menu Scene" I call `storyboard.goToScene("game")`
- Inside `CreateScene` in "game" I create my `DisplayObject` and insert
  them to the `GroupView` (`scene.view`)
- Further in my code, I create various `DisplayObjects` (balls) with physics and add them to `scene.view` through

  ```
  stageGroupView:insert(ball)
  ```

  *`stageGroupView`* is a local variable declared on top of the module assigned with display.getCurrentStage( ) in CreateScene of "game"
- When a condition is met inside my collision detectors, I call goToScene("menu") wich, if I understood well, execute the exitScene listener of my "game" scene.
- Inside "exitScene" I remove all my listeners and timers
- Inside "didExitScene" I've tried to purge/remove the scene but everytime I get the aforementioned runtime error.

At this point, if I leave didExitScene empty, the storyboard does it's work but the game scene.view doesn't get erased. I just want to know **an effective way of adding dinamically created DisplayObject to my scene.view** and be able to **purge/remove my scene without runtime error**.

Here's some parts of my code for better understanding:

```
local function addBall(ball)
     stageGroupView:insert(ball)
end

function scene:exitScene( event )
local group = self.view

timer.cancel( spawnTimer )
timer.cancel( gameTimer )

background:removeEventListener( "touch", onTouch )
player:removeEventListener( "touch", onTouch )
player:removeEventListener( "collision", onPlayerCollision )
bottomBorder:removeEventListener( "collision", onBottomBorderCollision )
rightBorder:removeEventListener( "collision", onRightBorderCollision )
end


function scene:didExitScene(event)

--local group = self.view
--group:removeSelf()
storyboard.purgeScene( "game" )

end
```

As you can see I even tried group:removeSelf() to erase my scene.view, but with scarse results... Another runtime error pops up triggered by "menu" goToScene("game") once I exit and re-enter "game" scene:

> bad argument #-2 to 'insert" (Proxy expected, got nil) in function
>   'insert' ?:in function 'goToScene' in menu.lua.

Comment: Please show `didRemoveScene` function and from where it is called.

Comment: @Schollii I'm sorry, I made a mistake in the question. The function didRemoveScene doesn't exist in my code, it was a sort of typo for didExitScene wich is the true place where I attempt to remove/purge the game scene. -- (Edited the question!)

Comment: Then please correct your post and fix formatting of code so indented.

Comment: There are still 2 refs to `didRemoveListeners` in your post (title and error message, I could replace but I wouldn't want to mess anything up).

Answer (score 0):

I request you to call storyboard.removeScene( MenuScene) before you cal the game scene. Dont not use purge scene since it will not free all the memory. Make sure that you all your display objects are inserted in to the self.view. Any doubts regarding the purge scene and remove scene check it here :http://coronalabs.com/blog/2012/07/31/storyboard-scene-purging-vs-removal/